# OpenNI2 and ROS modules from source on NVidia Jetson TK1

Tags: ros, asus-xtion-pro-live, openni2-camera, openni2, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm porting OpenNI2 for Asus Xtion Pro Live on my robot. I succeded in compiling OpenNI2 and I can view RGB and Depth stream using rqt visualization plugin.

I wrote a guide and I published it on the website of my project:
http://myzharbot.robot-home.it/blog/software/configuration-nvidia-jetson-tk1/asus-xtion-pro-live-openni2-compilation-install-instructions/

My configuration has a problem: I cannot run "openni2_launch" correctly to get rgb pointcloud.

Am I missing something in my installation process?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200675/openni2-and-ros-modules-from-source-on-nvidia-jetson-tk1/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-09**:
All of those packages should be available through apt if you're using the UbuntuARM repository. Why are you building them from source?

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-01-09**:
Because the first time that I tried using Asus XTion Pro Live (with last kernel) I could not connect it.

Which package should I install? I saw in another thread that you are using the Asus on the Jetson...

Another doubt I have is relative to OpenCV... does ROS recognize correctly opecv4tegra?

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-01-10**:
I removed the packages and installed them from repo.
The sensor works.

I noticed that it installed libopenni2 even if there is the one that I compiled by myself.

I modified launch file to activate sync and hw registration. RGB and Depth streams are ok, but pointcloud2 streams are really slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer your question and comments:

In general, you should try to install packages through the package manager. This will save you time, and makes it easier to debug problems because you'll be using the exact same binaries as the rest of the community; you won't have to try to debug differences in compiler flags, build types or build flags. If you do have to install a package from source, give a short explanation of why you can't use the packaged version.

Most package managers don't recognize when you have packages installed from source, and apt is no exception. This is not an appropriate forum to discuss the reasons for this limitation; if you're really interested, do some searching and/or go read the design documentation for apt.

"Really Slow" doesn't mean anything to me; for a couple of reasons:

- everyone has a different definition of slow and fast. 5Hz might be "fast" for me, but it's slow for someone who is used to working with 30Hz or 1000Hz data streams.
- It doesn't capture how you're measuring the speed of the pointcloud stream.

A much better question might be "I tried to view pointclouds in rviz, and I'm only seeing them at 1-2Hz" or "I used `rostopic hz` to measure the speed of the pointcloud topic, and I'm only getting 8Hz". Mentioning your desired speed is also useful.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-01-10**:
Thank you for your exhaustive reply. I tried to compile OpenNI2 and the packages to use RGB-D by myself because a few time ago I did not succeeded with the repo version. Today I used the openni2_camera, openni2_launch and rgbd_launch and they worked well.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-01-10**:
I also solved the problem with the "speed" (only 1-2 Hz using rostopic hz /camera/depth_registered/points). The Jetson TK1 boots with only 1 core active of the 4 available. I activate them at boot and set "performance" as governor, reaching 30 hz both on the Jetson and on the remote PC using rviz wi